PLL Phase Error Detectors for non-bandpass-communication type signals
I'm quite familiar with PLLs for bandpass signals (e.g., GPS) which operate on IF or complex baseband signals.  However, I now have a phase tracking problem where the signal is not necessarily concentrated around a carrier.  Consider samples of a received signal of the form:
$y(t)=A \cos(\theta(t)) \qquad t\in kT_s$.
Nominally, this signal may contain a usually slowly varying frequency term along with a slowly varying phase drift component: $\theta(t) = \int^t_{-\infty} \omega(\tau)d\tau + \psi(t)$.  Unlike say RF communications or GPS, the slowly varying frequency term is not nominally centered at some known (carrier) frequency but is restricted to a band: $\omega(t) \in [0, \omega_{max}]$ where $\omega_{max}$ is much lower than the Nyquist frequency.  Under important special cases, $\omega(t)$ can, for a period of time, even fall to zero.
I'm wondering about the type of phase error detector (PED) I can use for a problem like this.  I could force this problem to be more like those for standard carrier-based scenarios by removing the negative frequency components, giving rise to a complex-baseband type signal similar to zero IF scenarios.  This would effectively give me a signal of the form $\frac{A}{2} e^{j\theta(t)}$.  However, the filtering operation to generate this signal would introduce unwanted delay into the system.  (This is supposed to be a real-time phase tracker).
I know that PLLs are used in many applications and that there are many different PEDs.  Which ones would make the most sense for an application like mine?
As an alternative, I'm wondering whether simply using an Extended Kalman Filter is preferable.

If SNR is high, you could consider a time based zero crossing measurement of "phase". For real signals “phase” is with relation to a reference signal, so something needs to be your point of reference and you would measure the time delay from edges of your reference. Instantaneous Frequency is the derivative of this or the change of phase vs change in time, so you would be measuring both. With zero crossing measurements you would only be able to get the update of what phase is at those moments in time, so you would from that get a discrete time waveform of what the phase is vs time.
